# Chartjs splitting double digit numbers

Tags: javascript, python, django, chart.js

I have seen this question asked a few times but I couldn't find a solution that worked for me.

I am passing a Django variable into Chartjs to plot, all of the single-digit numbers are correct but it turns double-digits into single. Like 11 is 1,1...23 is 2,3.

I have tried a bunch of different ways but cant figure it out, I appreciate any help you can offer.

```html
    var home_runs = '{% for game in all_games.home_ten %}{{ game.runs }}{% endfor %}'
```

```js
        var ctx = document.getElementById('runChart').getContext('2d');
        var runChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: labels,
            datasets: [
                {
                  label: home_team,
                  data: home_runs
                },
                {
                  label: away_team,
                  data: away_runs,
                    
                    ],
                    }
            ]
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true,
        },
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can push that values inside array instead of directly passing them to your `data`. So , you can add this in your js code i.e :

```
  var home_runs = [];
  '{% for game in all_games.home_ten %}'
     home_runs.push(parseInt('{{ game.runs }}'))
  '{% endfor %}'
```

***Demo Code*** :

```js
/* var home_runs = [];
 {% for game in all_games.home_ten %}
home_runs.push(parseInt('{{ game.runs }}'))
{% endfor %}*/
var home_runs = [11, 52, 85, 93]
var away_runs = [12, 52, 82, 94]
var ctx = document.getElementById('runChart').getContext('2d');
var runChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["A", "B", "C", "D"],
    datasets: [{
        label: "Abc",
        data: home_runs
      },
      {
        label: "Xyz",
        data: away_runs

      }
    ],
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
  },
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<div>
  <canvas id="runChart" height="140"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow.. you did it again! Thank you so much, hopefully one day I'm as smart as you :)

Comment: The only thing I would add to your answer for anyone else that needs this info is you forgot the quotes around the for statement.

Comment: var home_runs = [];
  '{% for game in all_games.home_ten %}'
        home_runs.push(parseInt('{{ game.runs }}'))
  '{% endfor %}'

Comment: I didn't tested this with django but similar code work with `jsp` so i thought quotes are not needed . I will add that in my answer :)